# Total angular momentum

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum

I have a question regarding total angular momentum. I have spoken about this topic with master students or tutors etc but I cannot really understand the logic behind what I am about to ask. It is not that I do not understand, more that I find it not correct what the others explained to me. I will write my question here and try to be as precise as I can be.

The example is an electron with spin and orbital angular momentum.
That means we have an $S$ and an $L$. In the lecture, the professor told us that :

The total angular momentum $J$ $(J=L+S)$ has the following values, I guess :

$j=l+1/2$ and $j=l-1/2 $
(notice he uses a small $j$, which I take it is the total angular quantum number, explained further down). I do not get why he gets those 2 values.

For and arbitrary total angular momentum $J$, which is sum of 2 different arbitrary angular momenta, $J_1$ and $J_2$, we have :

$$J= J_1 + J_2$$

Now, we know that $J_1$ and $J_2$ can represent different types of angular momentum (movements), such as $S$, $L$, or others.

If $J_1=L$, then the following must be true :

$L$ (orbital angular momentum), $l$(orbital quantum number), $m_l$(orbital magn. quantum number), ${\left(l(l+1)\hbar^2\right) } ^{1/2}$ (eigenvalue of L).

For the arbitrary $j_1$, we would have in general :

$J_1$ (angular motion of some sort i.e $L$,$S$ etc), $j_1$ (equivalent of $l$ for $L$, I do not know how to name this),$m_{j_1}$ (equivalent of $m_l$ when $J_1$ is $L$) and $\left(j_1(j_1+1)\hbar^2\right)^{1/2}$  (eigenvalue of $J_1$).

The same reasoning is valid for $J_2$.

Therefore, for the total angular momentum J, the following (I assume) holds :

$J=J_1+J_2$ (total angular momentum). ($J=L+S$).

$j=j_1 + j_2$ (total angular corresponding quantum number).$j=l+s(=1/2)$ (here $s$ has only the value $1/2$)

$m_j=m_{j_1}+m_{j_2}$ (total angular magn. corresponding quantum number).$m_j=m_s+m_l$ (it is here were you encounter the $\pm$ values of spin).

Now, what we do in our example is :

$$j= l \pm 1/2$$

Basically, we are summing the orbital quantum number with the spin magnetic quantum numbers instead of with spin itself, which has value $\frac{1}{2}$. This is my question, how do we get to these 2 values.

I also know that the total angular momentum has values : $|J_1-J_2|<J<J_1+J_2$

Comment: you have "I also know that the total angular momentum has values : |J1-J2|<J<J1+J2" and also "j=l+1/2 and j=l-1/2 (notice he uses a small j,which i take it is the total angular quantum number,explained further down).I do not get why he gets those 2 values."  Those statements appear contradictory.

Comment: You 'know' that last statement. Do you know what it 'means'?

Comment: i assume  |J1-J2|<J<J1+J2 must be  j1-j2|<j<j1+j2 ?

Comment: at this point i am over-complicating the things,which results in me not understanding anything at all now. idk what to say. All i can assume is that J and j represent two different things. The big J is the total angular momentum as a vector operator while small j has to be the respective quantum number but i am not sure.

Comment: It appears your troubles stem from a confusion about the precise nature of these procedures. All of these things are covered in Sakurai's QM book in detail. That is, derived, not simply asserted. Though it is somewhat more demanding of the student than something like Griffiths.

Comment: Richard , could you tell me which section on Sakurai's book can i find what i am looking for?